# sql query words that don't have numbers?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

It is possible to select just words that don't contain numbers?

Something like...

```
|Address        |
-----------------
|Street x 150   |
|Street y       |
|Street z 498Z  |
```

I want just **Street y** in this case.

I have these texts in a excel, and would 'filter' in access. And in last try I can pass it to a SQL Server (microsoft).

I'll search about REGEX on Access or mssql.

Comment: Have you looked at your particular brand SQL's regex functions?

Comment: A REGEX function can do the trick.

Comment: I would suggest selecting the whole address, unless that selects thousands of _extra_ records, and then parsing that in the language you're using. Databases are good at storing and retrieving information.

Comment: At least MSSQL doesn't support regex functions; they have to be created manually ... if it's possible in your case, you can do that. Otherwise you can do 10x where-clauses, connected with "or" with the like operator ...

Comment: A WHERE condition and a RegEx like ^[^\d]+$ might get the job done but the exact syntax would depend on your RDBMS.  EDIT: Sorry- see other people have made the same comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do it in SQL Server (and most other databases):

```
select *
from t
where address not like '%[0-9]%'
```

That is, the address is not like something that has a number in it.

`Like` in Access does not follow the standard at all (using `*` rather than `%` as the wildcard, for instance).  So, this will not work in Access.

Comment: This don't solve my problem, however the problem doesn't exist anymore. I don't need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ... FROM ...WHERE fieldname REGEXP [^0-9]
```

Comment: Do you know which type of database the OP is using?

Comment: No.  To the best of my knowledge, regular expressions have been a part of the SQL standard since 1999; I don't know which db's do, or don't, implement that.

Comment: Go and try that on Oracle or SQL server.

Comment: Oracle -- regexp_LIKE, SQL Server -- dbo.RegexpMatch